# Can't see the custom shipping method just added

Tags: magento-2.1, module, shipping-methods

I need to add a custom shipping method. I was fallowging this tutorial: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-shipping-method/ 
I was able to configure my custom shipping method. I set enable "Yes", but I can't see my option for shipping, when I place an order. 
In the checkout window shipping methods appear empty. Thanks!

Comment: php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: you need to run upgrade command to enable Simple Shipping method.

Comment: Hello @Daniel have you checked the solution ?

Comment: Hi @AdityaShah, thanks for your answer. I tried your suggestions and the problems is still there? Another idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to run upgrade command to enable Simple Shipping method.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**and still if doesn't work then...**

> **For Magento 2.2.5**

please change the system config enable to **active**

> You will need to edit it in these files:

1. `app/code/Mageplaza/Simpleshipping/etc/config.xml` at line 6.
2. `app/code/Mageplaza/Simpleshipping/Model/Carrier/Shipping.php` at line 53.
3. `app/code/Mageplaza/Simpleshipping/etc/adminhtml/system.xml` at line 10.

Then make sure to `clean/flush` Magento cache.

Comment: Hey @Aditya thanks for that. Now is working!! I am with version Magento 2.1.15, but anyway I needed the changes in the config files.

Comment: You're welcome (: